# Essas falas da Dilma possuem erros de regência?

Tags: regência

As seguintes falas da Presidenta Dilma possuem erros de regência nominal ou verbal? Onde e por quê?

> "i da gente poder estocar, o vento podia ser isso também mas voce não
>   conseguiu ainda tecnologia pra estocar vento. Ter uma forma docê
>   estocar por que o vento ele é diferente nas horas do dia”
>
> “Se hoje é o dia das crianças. Ontem eu disse que criança. O dia da
>   criança é dia da mãe do pai e das professoras, mas também é o dia dos
>   animais. Sempre que você olha uma criança, há sempre uma figura oculta
>   que é um cachorro atrás”
>
> “Nós tamos comungando a mandioca com o milho e certamente teremos uma
>   série de outros produtos que foram essenciais  para o desenvolvimento
>   de toda a civilização humana ao longo dos séculos. Aqui hoje eu to
>   saudando a mandioca”
>
> “Eu vi. Você, veja... Eu já vi, parei de ver. Voltei a ver e acho que
>   o Neymar e o Ganso têm essa capacidade de fazer a gente olhar”
>
> Ai você fala o seguinte: 'Mas vocês acabaram isso?' Vou te falar:
>   ‘Não, está em andamento!’ Tem obras que vai durar pra depois de 2010.
>   Agora por isso nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do
>   que nós podemos fazê…
>
> Depois que a pasta de dente sai do dentifrício ela dificilmente volta
>   pra dentro do dentifrício, então ele me disse que faria todo o esforço
>   político pelo menos não ficasse solta por ai e voltasse uma parte
>   devolta pro dentifrício.
>
> A unica area que eu acho, que vai exigir muita atenção nossa, e ai eu
>   já aventei a hipótese de ate criar um ministério, é na area de.. na
>   area… eu diria assim, como uma especie de analogia com o que acontece
>   na area agrícola

Comment: A pergunta deveria apresentar a dúvida concreta, com a citação necessária, mas não mais do que a necessária, para que se compreenda qual é a dúvida. Dúvidas de naturezas diferentes seriam melhor apresentadas em perguntas separadas. Tal como está, pedindo para identificar erros de concordância num texto longo, a pergunta não é apropriada para o site.

Comment: Parece que o OP fez um perfil só para fazer essa pergunta.   O user525 postou em  outubro de 2015 e desde então nunca mais apareceu por aqui.  Provavelmente alguém que fez um segundo perfil apenas para uma finalidade política: chamar a atenção para os erros da ex-presidente.  Alguém que coleciona todos os erros de português de um terceiro, não tem boas intenções.

Answer (score 7):

Eu não vejo problemas de regência nessas frases (o que não quer dizer que não haja; talvez alguém acabe me provando o contrário). Sintaticamente falando, acho que a característica mais saliente são as orações curtas e incompletas, próprias da linguagem oral. Por exemplo,

> A única área que eu acho que vai exigir muita atenção nossa, e aí eu já levantei a hipótese...

Nessa frase, a Dilma começa com uma oração que pede um predicado ("A única área..."), mas o predicado não vem na frase. Supõe-se que ela começou a frase com a intenção de emendar algo como "... [a área] é área agrícola", mas mudou de ideia antes de terminá-la.

Há também um problema de concordância verbal entre um sujeito no plural e um verbo no singular:

> Tem obras que vai durar...

Ou mesmo um uso do pretérito imperfeito em vez do futuro do pretérito:

> [...] o vento podia ser [em vez de "poderia ser"]

Mais uma vez, esses "erros" são bastante comuns em falantes nativos de português brasileiro, especialmente em algumas regiões, como o estado de São Paulo. Mas, estritamente falando, não se trata de um problema de regência.

Por outro lado, há alguns problemas na *transcrição* do texto, que omite alguns acentos, usa pontuação incoerente, e escolhe grafias que imitam a fala em pontos que discordam da norma padrão da escrita. O efeito resultante é exacerbar o aspecto oral, fragmentado do discurso. Por exemplo,

> [...] o vento podia ser isso também mas voce não conseguiu ainda tecnologia pra estocar vento. Ter uma forma docê estocar por que o vento ele é diferente nas horas do dia.

Para mim, a estrutura da frase acima é a seguinte:

> [...] o vento podia ser isso também, mas você não conseguiu ainda tecnologia para estocar vento, ter uma forma de você estocar; porque o vento, ele é diferente nas horas do dia.

Ou seja, "ter uma forma de estocar" está subordinada à preposição "para" que vem logo antes. A frase é redundante e não muito polida, mas me parece significativamente menos chocante que a transcrição original.

Comment: Eu iria mais longe ainda. No discurso há pausas muito longas que facilitam a compreensão, e às quais nem a vírgula faz justiça. Eu transcreveria assim: "O vento podia ser isso também, mas você não conseguiu ainda tecnologia para estocar vento ― ter uma forma de você estocar ― porque o vento, ele é diferente nas horas do dia."